# Prevent onScroll function from executing again until finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, css-transitions

I'm building a variation on a slideshow where the slides fade in/out when the user scrolls up/down. The basic process is this:

1. The user moves their scrollwheel
2. Detect the movement with `$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel')`
3. Detect if the scroll was up or down and track how much it was scrolled
4. Once the scroll amount reaches a threshold in either direction, show the prev/next slide depending on the scroll direction

The problem is that on some devices, specifically trackpads and 'magic' mouses (touch), the `onScroll` function executes several times. I'd like the function to run once, finish, then wait for additional `onScroll` events before running again.

Here's a simplified version of my code.

```
$(function() {


  var delta = 0;
  var wait = false;
  var scrollThreshold = 5;

  $(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e){  

    if (wait === false) {

      // If the scroll is up
      if (e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {

        // Track the amount of scroll
        delta = Math.min(0,delta - 1);

        if ( Math.abs(delta) >= scrollThreshold) {


          wait = true;

          // Go to the previous slide
          // This changes the class of the current and previous slides
          // causing several CSS transitions.
          $(active).removeClass('active');
          $(prev).addClass('active').removeClass('zoom');

          $(active, prev).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {

            wait = false; 
            delta = 0;

          });

        }

      // If the scroll is down
      } else {

        // Track the amount of scroll
        delta = Math.max(0,delta + 1);

        if ( Math.abs(delta) >= scrollThreshold) {

          wait = true;

          // Go to the next slide
          // This changes the class of the current and next slides
          // causing several CSS transitions.
          $(active).addClass('zoom').removeClass('active');
          $(next).addClass('active');

          $(active, next).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {      

            wait = false; 
            delta = 0;

          });

        }

      }

    }

  });
```

The problem is the `wait` flag doesn't prevent the function from running again on touchpads and 'magic' mouses.

What's the recommended method for making the function run once, then wait until it's finished before it listens for new scroll events and runs again?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) library (its fantastic) there is a function called _.debounce that will accomplish what you are trying to do.

here is the code for the function.  the comments from the library explains it perfectly :-)

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
_.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

edit: here is the code from [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) refactoring this function to use on its own

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        }, wait);
        if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Example usage

```
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```

Comment: Interesting. If it's possible to do without an additional JS library I'd prefer that route. I'll keep this on the backburner however.

Comment: There are also some custom jQuery `.debounce()` functions but the ones I've seen are based on time and not the amount of scroll, unfortunately.

Comment: I updated it to include a function that can be used on its own without including another library.  Source was from David Walsh.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case. The function still runs through several slides if I move my trackpad too much, too quickly.